# Reading a bag file with hector slam package

Tags: ros, lidar, hector-slam, 2d-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a neato XV-11 lidar and I am able to record a bag file. However when I run the launch file in this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam/Tutorials/MappingUsingLoggedData with my bag file I get the following error

```
[ INFO] [1455077561.968539391, 1454655528.267204049]: lookupTransform base_footprint to neato_laser timed out. Could not transform laser scan into base_frame.
```

Can anyone help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226184/reading-a-bag-file-with-hector-slam-package/) by [jaymo3141](https://answers.ros.org/users/25794/jaymo3141/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-02-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-10**:
When copy/pasting console output it's better to format it as *Preformatted text* (the button with `101010` on it). That way illegal markup (like the `[ INFO ]`) does not get filtered out (your error message was invisible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There was another ROS Answer thread about that exact error (well, almost exact--it wasn't about a neato_laser, just laser), and in the thread it was determined that this is just an informational message (hence the [INFO] label) that occurs in the short time before the transform has spun up.

In other words, all you have to do is wait and the problem will go away on its own.

---

Originally posted by [dchang0](https://answers.ros.org/users/25414/dchang0/) with karma: 187 on 2016-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dchang0](https://answers.ros.org/users/25414/dchang0/) on 2016-02-12**:
Here is the other thread: http://answers.ros.org/question/53611/hector_mapping-base_link-laser-transform-times-out-once/